# Short-Term Research Programs for International Students

Tags: europe, international-students, research-assistantship, australia

I will finish my MS soon and I will apply for fall 2016-PhD. I am wondering is there any short-term research assistance program ( 6-9 months) especially in Australia or European countries? If there are, how can I find them?(I don't mean summer schools which are mostly for undergrads)
I should mention that I am from Iran, and I have studied in the best university here but most of the international programs support students from limited countries, so finding a short-term program which admits people from all over the world has been really hard for me.

Comment: Try out the DAAD's scholarship database: https://www.daad.de/deutschland/stipendium/en/ the search can be refined based on your nationality and your field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Australia: Endeavour Research Fellowships offer a 4-6 month research trip to Australia for most countries, including Iran ([Endeavour](https://internationaleducation.gov.au/endeavour%20program/scholarships-and-fellowships/international-applicants/pages/international-applicants.aspx)).

For Europe: As mentioned in the comments, the DAAD offers a number of different scholarships for research trips to Germany. The Iran DAAD page is [here](http://ic.daad.de/teheran/ir/) and the pages for other countries can be easily found by searching.

For the USA: The Fulbright offers an exchange program for students to spend an academic year in the USA, but it isn't available for students from Iran ([Fulbright](http://www.iie.org/fulbright)).

Note that all these are for currently enrolled graduate students - if you are trying to fund research when you are in between a MS and a PhD then unfortunately I'm not sure how much luck you'll have.